# ¿Crear un JSON Object o un JSON Array?

Tags: json, array

Resulta que tengo tres tablas, `tablaA`, `tablaB`, `tablaC` y quiero generar un JSON con ello para poder mandarlo a otra base distinta, pero quiero separar las acciones pues en las tablas hay insert y updates que se diferencian por un campo llamado `accion` en cada tabla.

La pregunta es ¿cómo seria la estructura del JSON que guarde toda esa data para luego poder recorrerla y hacer los insert o los update depende de lo que venga?

He probado:

```
{
  tablaA: 
     insert: {
       campo:valor,
       campo:valor
     }
     update: {
       campo:valor,
       campo:valor
     }
 tablaB: 
   insert:{
     campo:valor,
     campo:valor
   }
   update:{
     campo:valor,
     campo:valor
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez esto pueda servir

**PHP**

```
<?
$tablas=array("tablaA","tablaB","tablaC");
$acciones=array("insert","update");
$campos=array(array("campoA","valorA","CondicionA"),array("campoB","valorB","CondicionB"),array("campoC","valorC","CondicionC"));

$json=array();
foreach($tablas as $row){
    foreach($acciones as $row2){
        foreach($campos as $row3){
            $json[$row][$row2][]=array($row3[0],$row3[1],$row3[2]);
        }
    }
}
$json=json_encode($json);
?>
```

El código PHP emula la carga del arreglo

**JS**

```
<script>
var Arreglo=$.parseJSON('<?=$json?>');
$.each(Arreglo,function(key,value){
    $.each(value,function(key2,value2){
        $.each(value2,function(key3,value3){
            var SQL="";
            if(SQL!="") SQL+=", ";
            if(key2=="insert") SQL+=value3[0]+"="+value3[1];
            if(key2=="update") SQL+=value3[0]+"="+value3[1]+" WHERE "+value3[2];
            if(key2=="insert") SQL="INSERT INTO "+key+" SET "+SQL;
            if(key2=="update") SQL="UPDATE "+key+" SET "+SQL;
            console.log(SQL);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

El código JS recorre ese arreglo y genera una cadena SQL por cada elemento

La respuesta de la consola es esta

```
INSERT INTO tablaA SET campoA=valorA
INSERT INTO tablaA SET campoB=valorB
INSERT INTO tablaA SET campoC=valorC
UPDATE tablaA SET campoA=valorA WHERE CondicionA
UPDATE tablaA SET campoB=valorB WHERE CondicionB
UPDATE tablaA SET campoC=valorC WHERE CondicionC
INSERT INTO tablaB SET campoA=valorA
INSERT INTO tablaB SET campoB=valorB
INSERT INTO tablaB SET campoC=valorC
UPDATE tablaB SET campoA=valorA WHERE CondicionA
UPDATE tablaB SET campoB=valorB WHERE CondicionB
UPDATE tablaB SET campoC=valorC WHERE CondicionC
INSERT INTO tablaC SET campoA=valorA
INSERT INTO tablaC SET campoB=valorB
INSERT INTO tablaC SET campoC=valorC
UPDATE tablaC SET campoA=valorA WHERE CondicionA
UPDATE tablaC SET campoB=valorB WHERE CondicionB
UPDATE tablaC SET campoC=valorC WHERE CondicionC
```

Comment: Las publicaciones en este sitio no deben incluir saludos, despedidas, firmas, slogans etc. que no aportan al contenido medular de la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

He logrado comprender como funciona JSON

Los JSONObject estas compuestos por llave => valor como esto: {"id":1}

Los JSONArray pueden tener muchos valores dentro de si como esto [1,2,3,4,5]

Lo que hice fue crear un array de insert y un array de update para cada tabla y luego todo eso dentro de un JSONObject

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray
jarray.put("primer insert", "segundo insert"...)
json.put("insert",jarray);
```

Y asi he creado mas array y los he colocado dentro del JSONObject